# EC2 Bitnami Wordpress debug log not displaying in wp-content

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have updated the wp-config.php file to display the WordPress debug logs with:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

However, the debug log is not being produced in the wp-content folder as is typically expected. What is even a bit odder is that

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

Should produce the debug info on the actual worpress interface and that is also not being displayed.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. Also `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/debug.log' );` doesn't help. However `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/tmp/debug.log' );` works. I suspect some permission/ownership issue on one of the folders leading up to `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to check if

```
display_errors
```

or

```
error_reporting
```

is active (not a comment) somewhere else in the ini file.

Turned om that there was a diplay_errors = off.

```
display_errors = on;
```

In ec2 create the log file on that path and give the file permission to log file.

Comment: None of these suggestions seem to be WordPress wp-config.php setting options.  Not sure where you are getting these suggestions from. Maybe my permissions are incorrect however it is the default EC2 bitnami WordPress instance with no changes.  I launched a separate instance to test and see if maybe I screwed up somewhere on the install and the standard config setting as I originally posted don't work on the new instance either.